# Move an element from std::deque in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move, deque

We know that `std::deque::front()` return a reference to a first element of deque.
I would to know if this code is always safe:

```
//deque of lambdas
deque<function<void(void)>> funs;

// then is some other place:
// take a lock
m.lock();
auto f = move(funs.front()); // move the first lambda in f
funs.pop_front(); // remove the element from deque //now the value is hold by f
m_.unlock(); // unlock the resorce
f(); //execute f
```

I've tried this code using gcc-4.9 and works but I don't know if we can consider this code safe!

Comment: It is almost a valid code. Almost - because you are not checking for emptiness. The moving of the stored element is a safe operation.

Comment: Typo report: You use `lock()` on `m` and `unlock()` on `m_`.

Comment: The biggest safety issue might be "using namespace std" ;)
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `std::function` move constructor is not guaranteed to not throw exceptions, so you have an exception safety issue. Since you are not using an RAII lock for `m`, it will remain locked if `auto f = move(funs.front());` throws. You can correct the problem with `std::unique_lock`:

```
std::unique_lock<decltype(m)> lock{m};
if (!funs.empty()) {
  auto f = move(funs.front()); // move the first lambda in f
  funs.pop_front(); // remove the element from deque //now the value is hold by f
  lock.unlock(); // unlock the resorce
  f(); //execute f
}
```

or `std::lock_guard`:

```
function<void()> f;
{
  std::lock_guard<decltype(m)> lock{m};
  if (!funs.empty()) {
    f = move(funs.front()); // move the first lambda in f
    funs.pop_front(); // remove the element from deque //now the value is hold by f
  }
}
if (f) f(); //execute f
```

Comment: Hi Casey, probably (for now) the best solution is the first one because in the second case the lambdas will stored into heap and for performance reason could be better to use auto

Comment: @GianLorenzoMeocci Why should `auto` give better performance? `auto f` in the first snippet will be identical to `decltype(move(funs.front())) f`. So by declaring `decltype(move(funs.front())) f` in the second snippet will give the same.

Comment: because using auto you'll store the lambdas in stack